# sorting 'N' dates without using built-in function

Tags: java, sorting, datetime

How to sort n dates without using a built in function? I was able to perform the operation using built in code.

```
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String dates[] = { "05-11-2014" , "23-08-2014" , "05-02-2013" };
for ( String string : dates ) {
    Date localdate=sdf.parse(string);
    list.add( localdate );
}
Collections.sort( list );
```

Here, I want to replace the `collections.sort()` function.

Comment: Why replace, if you want other order use from collections public static <T> void sort(List<T> list,
                            Comparator<? super T> c) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator)

Comment: @RobertWadowski ok il give it a try!!!

Comment: It sounds like you are supposed to implement a sorting algorithm yourself

Answer (score 0):

Here example, opposite order comparator

```
class Comp implements Comparator< Date >
{
    public int compare(Date o1, Date o2) {
        return -( o1.compareTo( o2 ) ); //implement here order you want
    }

}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String dates[] = { "05-11-2014" , "23-08-2014" , "05-02-2013" };
    List< Date > list = new ArrayList< Date >();
    for ( String string : dates ) {
        try {
            Date localdate = sdf.parse(string);
            list.add( localdate );
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Collections.sort( list );

    System.out.println( list );

    Collections.sort( list, new Comp() );

    System.out.println( list );
}
```

Result

```
[Tue Feb 05 00:00:00 CET 2013, Sat Aug 23 00:00:00 CEST 2014, Wed Nov 05 00:00:00 CET 2014]
[Wed Nov 05 00:00:00 CET 2014, Sat Aug 23 00:00:00 CEST 2014, Tue Feb 05 00:00:00 CET 2013]
```

Comment: yes this example helped me get through this ..thank you